# SQL Query to look up data by Date intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with statues, something like this:

```
Item     - Status - Date
12345    - 1 - 8/29/2015
12345    - 3 - 9/1/2015
12345    - 5 - 9/30/2015
22245    - 1 - 9/28/2015
22245    - 3 - 9/30/2015
```

What I need to do is have a query which returns something along the lines of:

```
Item - Status Today - Status 15 days ago - Status 30 days ago - Status 45 days ago
12345 -     5               5                    3                    1
22245 =     3               1                    1                    1
```

I can't figure out how to even do this in a query.

The interval is a set 15 days, and I need to know the status each item was in on that day.

Please help...

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a free code writing/homework help service.

Comment: your output doesnt make sense.  `12345` was status `3` 29 days ago so why are you showing status `5` for `Status 15 days ago` if it did not change to `5` until today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8f0e/1) or what I assume you're trying to achieve. using a query like this.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  s.Item,
            s.STATUS,
            DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), [Date]) DaysAgo
    FROM    Statuses s
),
statusCte AS (
    SELECT 
        Item,
        MIN(CASE WHEN DaysAgo = 0 THEN [Status] END) [Status Today],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DaysAgo Between -15 AND -1 THEN [Status] END) [Status 15 days ago],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DaysAgo Between -30 AND -16 THEN [Status] END) [Status 30 days ago],
        MIN(CASE WHEN DaysAgo < -30 THEN [Status] END) [Status 45 days ago]
    FROM
        cte
    GROUP BY
        Item
)
SELECT  
    Item,
    COALESCE([Status Today], [Status 15 days ago], [Status 30 days ago], [Status 45 days ago]) [Status Today],
    COALESCE([Status 15 days ago], [Status 30 days ago], [Status 45 days ago], [Status Today]) [Status 15 days ago],
    COALESCE([Status 30 days ago], [Status 45 days ago], [Status 15 days ago], [Status Today]) [Status 30 days ago],
    COALESCE([Status 45 days ago], [Status 30 days ago], [Status 15 days ago], [Status Today] ) [Status 45 days ago]
FROM 
    statusCte
```

Answer (score 0):

This should meet your expectations:

```
SELECT item,
    [0] AS [Status today],
    [15] AS [Status 15 days ago],
    [30] AS [Status 30 days ago],
    [45] AS [Status 45 days ago]
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
   (SELECT TOP 1 t2.status FROM dbo.test1 t2 WHERE t2.item = z.item AND DATEDIFF(DAY,t2.date,GETDATE()) >= x.part ORDER BY date DESC) AS status
  FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT t.item
     FROM dbo.test1 t) z
          CROSS JOIN
          (SELECT 0 AS part
          UNION SELECT 15
          UNION SELECT 30
          UNION SELECT 45) x ) sr
PIVOT
  (MAX(status) FOR part IN ([0],[15],[30],[45])) pvt
```